# Deciding which properties of linear transformations are true

Tags: linear-transformations

> For a linear transformation $T \colon V \to W$, choose which of the following are correct:
>
> a) $T$ preserves vector space operations.
> b) $T$ maps zero vector of $V$ to that of $W$.
> c) When $\dim V = m$, $\dim W = n$ and $T$ is invertible then $m$ equals $n$.
> d) When $\dim V = m$ and $\dim W = n$ then $T$ is invertible iff $m$ equals $n$.

---

I wonder if I'm thinking correctly:

About a), I think it means scalar multiplication and addition, so it's true.
About b), $T$ is linear, so it's true.
About c) and d), if a transformation maps $\mathbb{R}^{n=m}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n=m}$ then it's invertible, so it's true.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: (a), (b), (c): correct; (d): false

Comment: " a 4 by 3 matrix A and Rank(A)=3 " Would it be a counter example?

Comment: In (d) you have $m=n$. So how can your example be a counterexample???

Comment: For $[M]_{4 \times 3}  \cdot  x$, assume Rank(M)=3, and $x$ to span $\mathbb{R}^3$. then wouldn't m and n equal to 3?

Comment: I thought assuming x to span R3 means n=3, and the result of transformation will have form as mx+ny+lz and since m, n, and l are L.D., it has 3 basis which means m=3. Am I going wrong way?

Comment: I am not understanding a word, sorry.

Comment: Maybe I'm saying nonsense... T_T Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a transformation maps from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb {R}^m$, it need not be invertible. For example, consider the map which takes any element in $\mathbb{R}^m$ to the zero vector. This is neither one-one nor onto.

Comment: I'm not sure how your example fits into the mentioned transformation.

Comment: @nik: It does..

Comment: @nik This map is not invertible, even though it's from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Hence d) is false.

Comment: Could you explain how zero vector is considered to have a dim=m ?

Comment: The zero vector is the image, not the codomain. The dimension of the codomain is $m$ and the dimension of the image (zero vector) is $0$. When the dimension of the image and the codomain are the same, the map is onto.

Comment: I have no idea how assuming dim(codomain)=m leads to dim(W)=m.

Comment: @nik $W$ is the codomain.

Comment: For me, there should be m basis for W to have dim=m. What am I missing?

Comment: $W$ is just the codomain. The set of all elements in the codomain which have a pre-image in the domain (V), is the range. The range is always a subspace of the codomain and hence have dimension $\leq m$. When they have the same dimension, the codomain is the range. Such functions are called 'onto'.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'm having difficulty at understanding your answer. What I think is, If the transformation matrix maps any element in $\mathbb{R}^m$ to zero vector, zero vector is W(which is image or range) thus doesn't have a dimension of m. then why is dimW equal to m?

Comment: Zero vector is image, which has dimension $0$. This zero vector is part of a bigger vector space (in your case $W$) which is called the codomain. Here, the dimension of the codomain is $m$.

Answer (score 1):

a),b) and c) are true.

The iff in d) is false.   Any map that has nonzero kernel,  for instance,  won't be invertible.  (For a map to be invertible it must be one-one.)  Not every map between spaces of the same dimension is invertible.   For a trivial example,  consider the zero map (kernel is $V$), as @Sudheesh points out...  For other examples, consider any map whose rank is less than $n$ (of course, we only need one counterexample)...

Comment: Thanks. 'kernel is V' gave me some hint. I'll think about it more.

Comment: $\underbrace{(0,0,\dots,0)}_{\text{m-times}}$ is $\vec0\in\mathbb R^m$, btw

Comment: I can understand it does belong to $\mathbb{R}^m$, but how does it alone have dimension of m? Shouldn't there be m L.D. vectors?

Comment: It has $m$ coordinates.  Thus it is the $m$-dimensional zero vector.    Linear dependence is a different notion.  Good question, incidentally...

Comment: Sometimes just $0$ is written.

Comment: Are you saying zero vector has dimension of m because it's m by 1 matrix? But W is vector space thus its dimension depends on the number of L.D. basis. Am I going wrong way?

Comment: $\dim W=m$ means there are $m$ elements in a basis.  But every vector space contains $0$.